# "angular.bootstrap()" throws error when Angular version is updated

Tags: angularjs

Not sure if this is the appropriate place for this question, but when I simply updated my Angular script from 1.4.8 to 1.5.11, the UI bombs out and throws an error when attempting to do an `angular.bootstrap(...)`:

```
https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=ckwy4037000003e8twhn1wp0a&p1=Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=sn.common.attachments&p1=Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/nomod?p0=sn.common.attachments
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:9:426
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:28:235
    at b (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:27:282)
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:28:20
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:43:17
    at q (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:10:371)
    at g (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:42:382)
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:43:34
    at q (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:10:371)
    at g (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:42:382)
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:9:426
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:43:292
    at q (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:10:371)
    at g (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:42:382)
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:43:34
    at q (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:10:371)
    at g (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:42:382)
    at fb (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:46:381)
    at c (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:24:19)
    at Object.Gc [as bootstrap] (http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular_includes_1.5.11.jsx?v=Wed_Dec_08_12_09_54_PST_2021:24:332
```

...wondering if anyone else has come across this issue, and if they have an idea of what's going on?

I'm not really familiar with Angular, but from looking at the docs, when I compare between v1.4.8 and v1.5.11, the only difference I see is the two yellow banners - one in particular that says:

> Note: Do not bootstrap the app on an element with a directive that
> uses transclusion, such as `ngIf`, `ngInclude` and `ngView`. Doing this
> misplaces the app `$rootElement` and the app's `injector`, causing
> animations to stop working and making the injector inaccessible from
> outside the app.

This looks related, but I'm not 100% certain that that may be...

Comment: You need to provide more details. Otherwise, it's just guessing what could be done here. I would recommend to try smaller upgrade steps, meaning to start from 1.4.8, upgrade to 1.4.9, then 1.4.10, and so on, unless you come to the point where the error starts showing up. Then check the changelog for (backwards incompatible) changes between the two versions. Also, you should check whether your external libraries (if any) need to be upgraded as well.

Comment: Are you still providing `sn.common.attachments`, per [your error URL](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=ckwy4037000003e8twhn1wp0a&p1=Error:%20[$injector:modulerr]%20http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=sn.common.attachments&p1=Error:%20[$injector:nomod]%20http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/nomod?p0=sn.common.attachments)?

Comment: @twwwt the only difference is with the update of the Angular version... but thanks for the suggestion, I will take upon it and maybe approach it via a binary search approach with the version numbers to shave off some time!

Comment: @JeffBowman ahh, perhaps that is the case... let me see if those dependencies have been modified in our scripts...

Comment: @JeffBowman you were right! It was a bad path (changed the version number in the path, but that path doesn't exist for that version)... Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in the comments:

> Are you still providing `sn.common.attachments`, per [your error URL](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/error/%24injector/modulerr?p0=ckwy4037000003e8twhn1wp0a&p1=Error:%20%5B%24injector:modulerr%5D%20http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/%24injector/modulerr?p0=sn.common.attachments&p1=Error:%20%5B%24injector:nomod%5D%20http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/%24injector/nomod?p0=sn.common.attachments)?

> you were right! It was a bad path (changed the version number in the path, but that path doesn't exist for that version)... Thank you!!!!

Angular employs a technique where its error messages are encoded as URLs, which enables more-informative and translatable error messages without bloating the production app size. Consequently, that first `https://code.angularjs.org/` URL actually contains the real `$injector:nomod` error that the URL target describes. From there it's easier to see that the bootstrap failed due to the absence of a module, here `sn.common.attachments` specifically.